# WIll 12.04 have a keyboard backlight indicator?

Tags: keyboard, 12.04, backlight

I have a laptop which has a keyboard with a backlight. This works fine, brightness indicator, volume indicator, but nothing appears on for keyboard backlight.

Will 12.04 eventually have a keyboard backlight indicator? or I will be 5 years without one?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, 12.04 will not.

Comment: @RolandTaylor Why not? I guess you could explain a bit or give some insights.

Comment: I'd say it's fairly settled. Especially now, since the LTS is out and no, it does not have a backlight activation option/key press response. I'm hoping it will come in 12.10